# Нужна сложная обрезка текста в bash

Tags: linux, bash

Есть sql-ный дамп тестового чата, выглядит вледующим образом(привожу 3 строки ... форматирование кривое, поэтому кажется что их 6..выделил визуально ):

`INSERT INTO "TEST-MSG" VALUES(840,1,263,'#user1/$user2;1633cb6c61f369e6','user1','user1'X'6512864C7028DCB17F5DDEA3663CE51082BF461A5EEA2E5C1024D47F82172914'1439889518,61,2,0NULLNULL,'ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ 1)'NULLNULL3,4,1NULLNULL,3304554754,831352659);`

`INSERT INTO "TEST-MSG" VALUES(841,1,263,'#user1/$user2;1633cb6c61f369e6','user2','user2'X'6233268E7FEFB4773EE63E79E5FAD5C2290C069273C8B60AA734C2435CF7F542'1439889536,610NULLNULL,'ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ 2'NULLNULL3,4,1NULLNULL,585002415,153024551);`

`INSERT INTO "TEST-MSG"
VALUES(842,1,263,'#user1/$user2;1633cb6c61f369e6','user2','user2'X'81CADA68E5FF5BF22A5CDD01E33C061BDB7B68B7BF16D2C7602AAF17D2ABB922'1439889579,610NULLNULL,'ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ 3'NULLNULL3,4,1NULLNULL,1544146789,153024552);`

Как можно обрезать все подобные строки в цикле, чтобы на выходе в текстовом файле осталось только:

`#user1/$user2; ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ 1`

`#user1/$user2; ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ 2`

`#user1/$user2; ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ 3`

Скорее всего нужна комбинация sed, grep и awk.

Comment: bash тормознутый, если нужно быстро, парсер текста лучше на perl написать используя регулярные выражения.

Comment: Если напишите вариант на Перле, буду вам очень благодарен) Сам, к сожалению, его не знаю...поэтому, bash)

Comment: Не могу сказать что знаю Perl, но тем не менее пишу со "справочниками" иногда не очень простые скрипты.

Comment: Могу набросать на перле, только 2 вопроса: 1) обязательны ли `#` и `$` в `#user1/$user2` и 2) обязательно ли `NULLNULL` до и после сообщения.

Comment: Решетка и доллар не имеют особого значения - можно их смело обрезать) Проверил пару сотен строк - действительно все сообщения обрамлены в 610NULNUL ... NULNUL3

Comment: Можно еще пойти совсем другим путем: выполнить этот SQL-скрипт, залив данные в подходящую базу данных, а потом одним запросом вытащить нужное.

Comment: @Dofri, выкинуть их несложно, важно понимать, обязательно ли они присутствуют в исходном тексте.

Comment: да, воезде одна и та же структура, меняется только хеш.

Answer (score 2):

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $IN, '<', $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open file $ARGV[0]";

while (<$IN>) {
  if (/(#\w+\/\$\w+);.+NULLNULL,\'(.+)\'NULLNULL/g) {
    print "$1; $2\n";
  }
}

close($IN);
```

Выводит то, что выглядит как ...(#буквыицифры/$буквыицифры);...NULLNULL'(тело сообщения)'NULLNULL...

Если выкинуть строки с open и close и оставить `while (<>) {`, будет читать STDIN, можно будет сделать `cat filename | perl script.pl`

Если поправить вот так:

```
  if (/#(\w+)\/\$(\w+);.+NULLNULL,\'(.+)\'NULLNULL/g) {
    print "$1 $2 '$2'\n";
  }
```

, то будет выводить

```
user1 user2 'тело сообщения'
```

(но это уже не проверял)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
  print "$1 $2 $3 $4 '$5'\n" if (/#(\w+)\/\$(\w+);[^']+\',\'(\w+)\',\'(\w+).+NULLNULL,\'(.+)\'NULLNULL/g)
}
```

Попробуйте как-то так, должно вывести `user1 user2 user3 user4 'message'`, но не проверял.
UPD проверил, работает. Кладем в файл `xxx.pl`, делаем исполняемым, запускаем как `cat <исходный файл> | ./xxx.pl`
Если нужен только user3 или user4, уберите $4 или $3 соответственно
П.С. все бэкслеши перед одинарной кавычкой можно убрать, это я их в процессе отладки понапихал.

Comment: не сработает если не будет решетки и доллара, если они не всегда присутствуют, приведите, плз, пример строки без них.

Comment: я бы на его NULL-ы не ориентировался, тут лучше на запятые делать ставку и на одинарные кавычки.

Comment: @dsnk слишком много запятых и кавычек, неясно, как выбрать нужные.

Comment: @andy.37 немного не пойму вот эту переменную в вашем скрипте - $ARGV[0]. Можно как-то вместо нее подставить чтение прямо из файла? Не получается пока запустить скрипт чтоб потестировать.

Comment: @Dofri это значит - брать имя файла из первого аргумента командной строки. Скрипт работает, проверял.

Comment: @dsnk совершенно верно. Запускать `perl <имя_файла_со_скриптом> <имя_файла_с_текстом>`

Comment: @andy.37 В Linux достаточно файлу содержащему скрипт разрешить выполнение `chmod a+x имя_файла` и в первой строке скрипта вписать `#!/bin/perl`

Comment: Да, все получилось, спасибо!

Comment: @dsnk, Да ну, серьезно?!!! ;)

Comment: а как можно было бы дописать скрипт, чтобы он из вот такой строки:
`#user1/$user2;1633cb6c61f369e6','user3','user4'X'`
доставал еще поле user3 или user4 - без разницы)

Comment: @Dofri, дописал в ответе

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось) Ваш новый код даже короче)

Comment: @Dofri Примите ответ, если устраивает (галочка под ответом)

Answer (score 1):

Вот нужная регулярка:

```js
document.querySelector('output').textContent = document.querySelector('pre').textContent
.replace(/^INSERT INTO "TEST-MSG" VALUES\(\d+,\d+,\d+,'((?:''|[^';])+)(?:''|[^'])+'(?:,'(?:''|[^'])+'){2}X'(?:''|[^'])+'(?:\w+,){2,4}'((?:''|[^'])*)'\w+(?:,\w+){4}\);$/gim, "$1; $2")
```

```css
pre, output {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<pre>INSERT INTO "TEST-MSG" VALUES(840,1,263,'#user1/$user2;1633cb6c61f369e6','user1','user1'X'6512864C7028DCB17F5DDEA3663CE51082BF461A5EEA2E5C1024D47F82172914'1439889518,61,2,0NULLNULL,'ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ 1)'NULLNULL3,4,1NULLNULL,3304554754,831352659);
INSERT INTO "TEST-MSG" VALUES(841,1,263,'#user1/$user2;1633cb6c61f369e6','user2','user2'X'6233268E7FEFB4773EE63E79E5FAD5C2290C069273C8B60AA734C2435CF7F542'1439889536,610NULLNULL,'ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ 2'NULLNULL3,4,1NULLNULL,585002415,153024551);
INSERT INTO "TEST-MSG" VALUES(842,1,263,'#user1/$user2;1633cb6c61f369e6','user2','user2'X'81CADA68E5FF5BF22A5CDD01E33C061BDB7B68B7BF16D2C7602AAF17D2ABB922'1439889579,610NULLNULL,'ТЕСТОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ 3'NULLNULL3,4,1NULLNULL,1544146789,153024552);</pre>
<output></output>
```